# Is there an API or other library available for SQL reporting services XML?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

While I do not have the full context of all that goes on in the generation of reports using SRS, I have recently been tasked with creating customized reports which are used to print labels ( a fairly daunting task, considering the ease that the designer is supposed to offer ). Since these were all custom documents, I created them from the ground-up in a very iterative "how about now?" fashion when working with error messages that I was able to produce. These were all XML documents following the general syntax of:

```
<XML>
<Definitions>
    <Definition>
        <Report>
            <Body>
                <ReportItems>
                 . . .
                </ReportItems>
            </Body>
            <Page />
            <ReportParameters />
        </Report>
    </Definition>
</Definitions>
```

My problem resides in the mystical realm of the " . . . " shown in the sample template listed above. Rather sadly, I have not found a template even *this* simple online at any of the MSDN resources or otherwise, only some outdated instructions on how I might use the designer to achieve some fairly minimal adjustments.

Does anyone know where I might be able to find more detail as to where the XML node definitions might be laid out? For instance, within a

```
<Textbox>
```

node, you have a set up like this:

```
<Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
        <TextRun>
            <Value>Here's some text that will display on the report</Value>
```

before you get down to actually flushing the thing out. At this point, I may want to do other things with my text, like adjust the size, weight etc. Only through intentionally breaking things am I able to get information regarding what is expected in this region, which would include (but probably is not limited to) the following:

Border, TopBorder, BottomBorder, LeftBorder, RightBorder, BackgroundColor, BackgroundGradientType, BackgroundGradientEndColor, BackgroundHatchType, BackgroundImage, FontStyle, FontFamily, FontSize, FontWeight, Format, TextDecoration, TextAlign, TextEffect, VerticalAlign, Color, ShadowColor, ShadowOffset, PaddingLeft, PaddingRight, PaddingTop, PaddingBottom, LineHeight, Direction, WritingMode, Language, UnicodeBiDi, Calendar, NumeralLanguage, NumeralVariant.

That's much more useful than stabbing around in the dark dark world of blackboxed SRS, but I now have no context of knowing what each one of these nodes would expect unless I then break *that* node intentionally (throwing some garbage node in there like

```
<asdflolbutts>
```

and getting it to maybe spit me back a similar message. As you can see, very inefficient.

Any and all help would be appreciated in running down some more useful information, otherwise I may just conjure up something myself and try to put it up online. Meh.

Cheers, and thank you for at least taking the time to read about my plight.
devKev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .rdl file or "report definition language" file has documentation located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms155062.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd297486(SQL.100).aspx).
This maybe useful if you are doing some type of dynamic/custom report creation, however, Visual Studio contains a complete designer already. There are third party tools that extend and add to the api, telerik, for example, has an mvc report viewer for ssrs.

Comment: Ah HA! This is exactly the sort of thing that I am looking for - searching in the wrong places it seems. Thank you very much!